# Turning on a floor lamp with a regular wall switch with the lamp connected to a different outlet that is not controlled by the switch

Tags: smart-lights

I've a floor lamp in my bedroom which was connected to an outlet that was controlled by a regular in-wall switch near the door. I used to turn it on with that switch as I enter the room. Now we had to rearrange the bedroom and the light got moved to a different outlet which does not have a switch. That outlet gets power all the time and now we have to walk in few steps and turn the lamp on/off with the switch that comes with the lamp.

I would like to turn that lamp on with the regular in-wall switch near the door without walking in and turning it on/off with the switch that comes with the lamp.

Comment: buy a remote control power outlet ... not an IoT question

Comment: If the house is yours (not a rental), you could rewire. You can ask about that at [diy.se], or hire an electrician to do it.

Comment: I'm in a rental.

Answer (score 1):

As jsotola commented, a simple remote controlled outlet may solve your problem, if you're flexible with you're requirement of using the previously employed wall switch. This would be a cheap solution, and simple to implement.

If not, however, this can still be done with devices, whose remote control device can be inserted into the wall cutout where the wall switch sits in, but *behind* the wall switch. There are many devices on the market, and some even use a well known RF technology and protocol that allows the solution to be integrated into a smart home, if you happen to come up with the idea later. These devices also tend to be smarter than the simple solution from the first paragraph, enabling control also from a smartphone, or timed switching on/off of the lamp.

I have covered exactly this situation using WiFi, employing the open source firmware Tasmota. This particular one is not a plug-and-play solution. It requires a bit of (fairly easy) fiddling, but provides all the conveniences including access from abroad via VPN, without compromising privacy with a cloud. This may be overkill for you; it's of course up to you to decide what you need.